# which data type use for 4 digit decimal (##.##)

Tags: sql, decimal

Want to value for Employee Total Experience, So it's values like
2.6,3.11,11.7

so which data type is proper in sql table

Comment: decimal(4,2), i.e. total 4 digits of which 2 are decimals.

Comment: i fix it Decimal(5,2)

Answer (score 3):

Use `decimal`

If you can only have 2 decimal places after the comma then you could use

```
decimal(8,2)
```

where `8` is the maximal total length of the number including places after the comma.

Comment: +1; To elaborate on this answer, `decimal(8,2)` uses the same number of bytes for storage as `decimal(4,2)`. For SQL Server, you could even use `decimal(9,2)` as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). Since you should never use SQL datatypes to validate user input (this should happen in the front end), you might as well go with the largest possible precision that uses the minimum amount of space necessary for the data you need to store.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this;

```
number(4,2)
```

4 is total count of your value.
2 is total count of value after comma.

ex:

> 12,34 .  it has 4 digit and 2 digit after comma. -> number(4,2) or
>
> 12345,2 it has 6 digit and 1 digit after comma. -> number(6,1)